# Как правильно создать zip скрипт в ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Есть некие файлы, например:

> /mnt/up/453434453.bak
>
> /mnt/up/rtytr45345.bak
>
> /mnt/up/cvbf5545ff.bak

Нужно, чтобы получились:

> /mnt/backup/453434453.zip
>
> /mnt/backup/rtytr45345.zip
>
> /mnt/backup/cvbf5545ff.zip

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно сохранить суффикс `.bak`, то так:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /mnt/up/*.bak
do
    zip /mnt/backup/`basename $f`.zip $f
done
```

Если нужно убрать, то, например, так:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /mnt/up/*.bak
do
    zip /mnt/backup/`basename $f .bak`.zip $f
done
```

А можно и покрасивее, без использования `basename`, только средствами `bash`. С сохранением суффикса `.bak`

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /mnt/up/*.bak
do
    echo $f
    zip /mnt/backup/${f##*/}.zip $f
done
```

и без сохранения

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /mnt/up/*.bak
do
    ff=${f##*/}
    zip /mnt/backup/${ff%.*}.zip $f
done
```

Comment: В целом верно, но там еще папки разные (`/mnt/up/*.bak -> /mnt/backup/*.zip`), так что `basename` все же, видимо, понадобится.

Comment: @andy.37 Что-то я невнимателен стал... Просмотрел, что пути разные...